# How to solve for a variable in xor equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, boolean-algebra

I am very new to algebra with bitwise operators.

If i have 5x ^ 7x ^ 9x = 22

is it possible for me to solve for x (if so how is it done)? Do normal algebra techniques hold (factoring out x etc.?)

I know that if x = 2, then the above equation is true

((5 * 2) ^ (7 * 2) ^ (9 * 2)) = (10 ^ 14 ^ 18) = 22 (where, * is normal multiplication)

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please explain how the $\wedge$ operation works here? This doesn't seem like usual Boolean algebra to me.

Comment: What is $5x$, ordinary multiplication in binary arithmetic or what?

Comment: @CameronWilliams in some programming language, "^" (not the wedge $\wedge$ ) stands for bitwise exclusive or operation.

Comment: @achillehui Yes I know what the exclusive or is, but I feel like details are missing.

Comment: The author is referring to bitwise exclusive or, and the equation the author wishes to solve is (5x)^(7x)^(9x)=22.

Comment: yes, ^ is the bitwise exclusive or. To be more specific I am using Python and Python does regular xor (https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators).                                       and by 5x I mean ordinary multiplication (5 * x). @CameronWilliams

Comment: @achillehui 5x is meant to be ordinary multiplication (5 * x).

Comment: Is this for a real-world application, or a class (and if so, what kind of course)?

Comment: Ahh I get you now. You mean to interpret the expressions in base 10, but then do the exclusive or on the binary representation of the numbers.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins This is for a cryptology class I am taking. Though we are not learning this exactly, we are learning about hashing algorithms that use xor in the manner above (a ^ b ^ c). As a hobby, I've been trying to see if I can reduce the complexity of some of the hashing algorithms and got stuck after I got to a similar equation to the one above where I need to solve for x. Just wanna know if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is possible for equations of the form:

$${\bigwedge}(a_ix+b_i)=C$$

(Here I just used $\wedge$ for bitwise xor.)

We will compute $x \pmod{2^m}$, increasing $m$ slowly. This method tries to reduce the "branching factor" when solutions are computed, not all numbers from $0$ to $2^m-1$ are necessarily tested. It's still not very efficient, and I'm yet to find a terminating condition other than "go large enough".

Let $m=1$. Then consider the parity of all the terms. Without further information, we can compute the parity of the left-hand side and the right-hand side. There are $3$ possibilities, either both $0, 1$ work, one of $0, 1$ work, or none of them work (which means no solution).

As we are only interested in finding roots, maybe there is really more than $1$ root. For example, $(3x)^\wedge(3x)=0$ has infinitely many solutions.

Suppose we know that a possible root $r$ satisfies $r\equiv n\pmod{2^m}$, so we want to be able to find the possible values of $r \pmod{2^{m+1}}$.

We take the entire equation $\pmod{2^{m+1}}$, and substitute the $2$ possible values of $r$, which are $r, r+2^m\pmod{2^{m+1}}$.

Let's use your example:

$(5x)^\wedge(7x)^\wedge(9x)=22$

Taking $\pmod2$, we obtain $x^\wedge x^\wedge x\equiv0$, so $x\equiv0\pmod2$

Taking $\pmod4$, we obtain $x^\wedge(3x)^\wedge x\equiv2$. This simplifies to $3x\equiv2$, so $x\equiv2\pmod4$.

Taking $\pmod8$, we obtain $(5x)^\wedge(7x)^\wedge x\equiv6$. Substituting $x\equiv2,6\pmod8$, we get that $2$ works, and $6$ does not.

Taking $\pmod{16}$, we obtain $(5x)^\wedge(7x)^\wedge(9x)\equiv6$. Substituting $x\equiv2,10\pmod{16}$, we get that both $2$ and $10$ work.

Taking $\pmod{32}$, we obtain $(5x)^\wedge(7x)^\wedge(9x)\equiv22$. Substituting $x\equiv2,10,18,26\pmod{32}$, we get that only $2$ works.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. One question I have is how are you obtaining the 2 values of r? For example how do you get 18,26 for (mod 32). @Element118